# Remove space in string representing numbers in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with numbers like '1 234' but they are string objects. And I tried to convert in float with `df[column].apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='float')`. I want to iterate of each column because the dataframe change and columns too.
The problem is it cannot convert in float because of the space. Is there a solution to remove space and then convert in float ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.replace` -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1 234', '2341']})
df['A'].str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
```

**Output**

```
0    1234.0
1    2341.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I iterate on each column and it raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['column'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True))
```

Or, if you expect decimals:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['column'].str.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I iterate on each column but it doesn't work

Comment: can you provide a complete input example?

Comment: Yes I put it in my question.

Comment: It's not reproducible, text would be better. Do you want to apply on all columns? If yes you can apply on the stacked dataframe, then unstack

Comment: Technically I don't want to apply on all columns but the dataframe change and it is unpredictable. One of my solution was to parse on all cells and if there is a space I remove it but it's not very efficient.